# HOWTO: Idiomatic Rust for callbacks with gtk (rust-gnome)

Tags: callback, gtk, rust, idioms, rust-gnome

I am currently learning Rust and looking to use it for developing a GUI
based application with GTK+. My problem relates to registering callbacks to
respond to GTK events/signals and mutating state within those callbacks.
I have a working but inelegant solution, so I would like to ask if there
is a cleaner, more idiomatic solution.

I have implemented my code as a struct with method implementations, where
the struct maintains references to the GTK widgets along with other state
that it needs. It constructs a closure that is passed to the
`GtkWidget::connect*` functions in order to receive events, draw to a
canvas, etc. This can cause problems with the borrow checker, as I will now
explain. I have some *working* but (IMHO) *non-ideal* code that I will
show.

**Initial, non-working solution:**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "gtk_3_10"), allow(unused_variables, unused_mut))]

extern crate gtk;
extern crate cairo;

use gtk::traits::*;
use gtk::signal::Inhibit;
use cairo::{Context, RectangleInt};


struct RenderingAPITestWindow {
    window: gtk::Window,
    drawing_area: gtk::DrawingArea,
    width: i32,
    height: i32
}

impl RenderingAPITestWindow {
    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> RenderingAPITestWindow {
        let window = gtk::Window::new(gtk::WindowType::TopLevel).unwrap();
        let drawing_area = gtk::DrawingArea::new().unwrap();
        drawing_area.set_size_request(width, height);
        window.set_title("Cairo API test");
        window.add(&drawing_area);

        let instance = RenderingAPITestWindow{window: window,
            drawing_area: drawing_area,
            width: width,
            height: height,
        };

        instance.drawing_area.connect_draw(|widget, cairo_context| {
            instance.on_draw(cairo_context);
            instance.drawing_area.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(true)
        });

        instance.drawing_area.connect_size_allocate(|widget, rect| {
            instance.on_size_allocate(rect);
        });

        instance.window.show_all();

        return instance;
    }

    fn exit_on_close(&self) {
        self.window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
            gtk::main_quit();
            Inhibit(true)
        });
    }


    fn on_draw(&mut self, cairo_ctx: Context) {
        cairo_ctx.save();
        cairo_ctx.move_to(50.0, (self.height as f64) * 0.5);
        cairo_ctx.set_font_size(18.0);
        cairo_ctx.show_text("The only curse they could afford to put on a tomb these days was 'Bugger Off'. --PTerry");
        cairo_ctx.restore();
    }

    fn on_size_allocate(&mut self, rect: &RectangleInt) {
        self.width = rect.width as i32;
        self.height = rect.height as i32;
    }
}


fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to initialize GTK."));
    println!("Major: {}, Minor: {}", gtk::get_major_version(), gtk::get_minor_version());

    let window = RenderingAPITestWindow::new(800, 500);
    window.exit_on_close();
    gtk::main();
}
```

The above fails to compile as the closures with
`RenderingAPITestWindow::new` that are created and passed to calls to
`GtkWidget::connect*` methods attempt to borrow `instance`. The
compiler states that the closures may outlive the function in which
they are declared and that `instance` is owned by the outer function,
hence the problem. Given that GTK may keep a reference to these closures
around for an unspecified amount of time, we need an approach in which the
lifetime can be determined at runtime, hence my next stab at the problem
in which the `RenderingAPITestWindow` instance is wrapped in
`Rc<RefCell<...>>`.

**Wrapping the `RenderingAPITestWindow` instance compiles but dies at runtime:**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "gtk_3_10"), allow(unused_variables, unused_mut))]

extern crate gtk;
extern crate cairo;

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use gtk::traits::*;
use gtk::signal::Inhibit;
use cairo::{Context, RectangleInt};


struct RenderingAPITestWindow {
    window: gtk::Window,
    drawing_area: gtk::DrawingArea,
    width: i32,
    height: i32
}

impl RenderingAPITestWindow {
    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<RenderingAPITestWindow>> {
        let window = gtk::Window::new(gtk::WindowType::TopLevel).unwrap();
        let drawing_area = gtk::DrawingArea::new().unwrap();
        drawing_area.set_size_request(width, height);
        window.set_title("Cairo API test");
        window.add(&drawing_area);

        let instance = RenderingAPITestWindow{window: window,
            drawing_area: drawing_area,
            width: width,
            height: height,
        };
        let wrapped_instance = Rc::new(RefCell::new(instance));

        let wrapped_instance_for_draw = wrapped_instance.clone();
        wrapped_instance.borrow().drawing_area.connect_draw(move |widget, cairo_context| {
            wrapped_instance_for_draw.borrow_mut().on_draw(cairo_context);

            wrapped_instance_for_draw.borrow().drawing_area.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(true)
        });

        let wrapped_instance_for_sizealloc = wrapped_instance.clone();
        wrapped_instance.borrow().drawing_area.connect_size_allocate(move |widget, rect| {
            wrapped_instance_for_sizealloc.borrow_mut().on_size_allocate(rect);
        });

        wrapped_instance.borrow().window.show_all();

        return wrapped_instance;
    }

    fn exit_on_close(&self) {
        self.window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
            gtk::main_quit();
            Inhibit(true)
        });
    }


    fn on_draw(&mut self, cairo_ctx: Context) {
        cairo_ctx.save();
        cairo_ctx.move_to(50.0, (self.height as f64) * 0.5);
        cairo_ctx.set_font_size(18.0);
        cairo_ctx.show_text("The only curse they could afford to put on a tomb these days was 'Bugger Off'. --PTerry");
        cairo_ctx.restore();
    }

    fn on_size_allocate(&mut self, rect: &RectangleInt) {
        self.width = rect.width as i32;
        self.height = rect.height as i32;
    }
}


fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to initialize GTK."));
    println!("Major: {}, Minor: {}", gtk::get_major_version(), gtk::get_minor_version());

    let wrapped_window = RenderingAPITestWindow::new(800, 500);
    wrapped_window.borrow().exit_on_close();
    gtk::main();
}
```

The above solution compiles but its not particularly pretty:

- `RenderingAPITestWindow::new` returns an
  `Rc<RefCell<RenderingAPITestWindow>>` rather than a
  `RenderingAPITestWindow`
- Accessing fields and methods of `RenderingAPITestWindow` is complicated
  by the fact that the `Rc<RefCell<...>>` must be opened up; it now requires
  `wrapped_instance.borrow().some_method(...)` rather than just
  `instance.some_method(...)`
- Each closure requires it's own clone of `wrapped_instance`; attempting
  to use `wrapped_instance` would attempt to borrow an object -- the
  wrapper rather than the `RenderingAPITestWindow` this time -- that is
  owned by `RenderingAPITestWindow::new` as before

While the above compiles, it dies at runtime with:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'RefCell<T> already borrowed', ../src/libcore/cell.rs:442
An unknown error occurred
```

This is due to the fact that the call to `window.show_all()` causes GTK to
initialise the widget hierarchy, resulting in the drawing area widget
receiving a `size-allocate` event. Accessing the window to call
`show_all()` required that the `Rc<RefCell<...>>` is opened (hence
`wrapped_instance.borrow().window.show_all();`) and the instance
borrowed. Before the borrow ends when `show_all()` returns, GTK invokes the
drawing area's `size-allocate` event handler, which causes the closure
connected to it (4 lines above) to be invoked. The closure attempts to
borrow a mutable reference to the `RenderingAPITestWindow` instance
(`wrapped_instance_for_sizealloc.borrow_mut().on_size_allocate(rect);`)
in order to invoke the `on_size_allocate` method. This attempts to borrow a
mutable reference, while the first immutable reference is still in scope.
This second borrow causes the run-time panic.

The *working* but - IMHO - inelegant solution that I have managed to get
working so far is to split `RenderingAPITestWindow` into two structs, with
the mutable state that is to modified by the callbacks moved into a
separate struct.

**Working but inelegant solution that splits the `RenderingAPITestWindow` struct:**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "gtk_3_10"), allow(unused_variables, unused_mut))]

extern crate gtk;
extern crate cairo;

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use gtk::traits::*;
use gtk::signal::Inhibit;
use cairo::{Context, RectangleInt};


struct RenderingAPITestWindowState {
    width: i32,
    height: i32
}

impl RenderingAPITestWindowState {
    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> RenderingAPITestWindowState {
        return RenderingAPITestWindowState{width: width, height: height};
    }

    fn on_draw(&mut self, cairo_ctx: Context) {
        cairo_ctx.save();
        cairo_ctx.move_to(50.0, (self.height as f64) * 0.5);
        cairo_ctx.set_font_size(18.0);
        cairo_ctx.show_text("The only curse they could afford to put on a tomb these days was 'Bugger Off'. --PTerry");
        cairo_ctx.restore();
    }

    fn on_size_allocate(&mut self, rect: &RectangleInt) {
        self.width = rect.width as i32;
        self.height = rect.height as i32;
    }
}


struct RenderingAPITestWindow {
    window: gtk::Window,
    drawing_area: gtk::DrawingArea,
    state: Rc<RefCell<RenderingAPITestWindowState>>
}

impl RenderingAPITestWindow {
    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<RenderingAPITestWindow>> {
        let window = gtk::Window::new(gtk::WindowType::TopLevel).unwrap();
        let drawing_area = gtk::DrawingArea::new().unwrap();
        drawing_area.set_size_request(width, height);
        window.set_title("Cairo API test");
        window.add(&drawing_area);

        let wrapped_state = Rc::new(RefCell::new(RenderingAPITestWindowState::new(width, height)))
        ;

        let instance = RenderingAPITestWindow{window: window,
            drawing_area: drawing_area,
            state: wrapped_state.clone()
        };
        let wrapped_instance = Rc::new(RefCell::new(instance));

        let wrapped_state_for_draw = wrapped_state.clone();
        let wrapped_instance_for_draw = wrapped_instance.clone();
        wrapped_instance.borrow().drawing_area.connect_draw(move |widget, cairo_context| {
            wrapped_state_for_draw.borrow_mut().on_draw(cairo_context);

            wrapped_instance_for_draw.borrow().drawing_area.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(true)
        });

        let wrapped_state_for_sizealloc = wrapped_state.clone();
        wrapped_instance.borrow().drawing_area.connect_size_allocate(move |widget, rect| {
            wrapped_state_for_sizealloc.borrow_mut().on_size_allocate(rect);
        });

        wrapped_instance.borrow().window.show_all();

        return wrapped_instance;
    }

    fn exit_on_close(&self) {
        self.window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
            gtk::main_quit();
            Inhibit(true)
        });
    }
}


fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to initialize GTK."));
    println!("Major: {}, Minor: {}", gtk::get_major_version(), gtk::get_minor_version());

    let wrapped_window = RenderingAPITestWindow::new(800, 500);
    wrapped_window.borrow().exit_on_close();
    gtk::main();
}
```

While the above code works as required, I would like to find a better way
for going forward; I would like to ask if anyone knows a better approach as
the above complicates the programming process a fair bit, with the need to
use `Rc<RefCell<...>>` and split structs to satisfy Rust's borrowing rules.

Comment: Because of auto-deref, I'm pretty sure all instances of `(*val.borrow())` and `(*val.borrow_mut())` can be replaced with `val.borrow()` and `val.borrow_mut()`.

Comment: "Given that GTK may keep a reference to these closures around for an unspecified amount of time" --- To me, this is the tip-off that you're going to need to use `Rc` if multiple closures need to access the same location in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; the `(*val.borrow())` occurrences have been replaced by `val.borrow()`. This makes things slightly prettier! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a working version that I came up with:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "gtk_3_10"), allow(unused_variables, unused_mut))]

extern crate gtk;
extern crate cairo;

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use gtk::traits::*;
use gtk::signal::Inhibit;
use cairo::{Context, RectangleInt};


struct RenderingAPITestWindow {
    window: gtk::Window,
    drawing_area: gtk::DrawingArea,
    state: RefCell<RenderingState>,
}

struct RenderingState {
    width: i32,
    height: i32,
}

impl RenderingAPITestWindow {
    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Rc<RenderingAPITestWindow> {
        let window = gtk::Window::new(gtk::WindowType::TopLevel).unwrap();
        let drawing_area = gtk::DrawingArea::new().unwrap();
        drawing_area.set_size_request(width, height);
        window.set_title("Cairo API test");
        window.add(&drawing_area);

        let instance = Rc::new(RenderingAPITestWindow {
            window: window,
            drawing_area: drawing_area,
            state: RefCell::new(RenderingState {
                width: width,
                height: height,
            }),
        });

        {
            let instance2 = instance.clone();
            instance.drawing_area.connect_draw(move |widget, cairo_context| {
                instance2.state.borrow().on_draw(cairo_context);
                instance2.drawing_area.queue_draw();
                Inhibit(true)
            });
        }
        {
            let instance2 = instance.clone();
            instance.drawing_area.connect_size_allocate(move |widget, rect| {
                instance2.state.borrow_mut().on_size_allocate(rect);
            });
        }
        instance.window.show_all();
        instance
    }

    fn exit_on_close(&self) {
        self.window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
            gtk::main_quit();
            Inhibit(true)
        });
    }
}

impl RenderingState {
    fn on_draw(&self, cairo_ctx: Context) {
        cairo_ctx.save();
        cairo_ctx.move_to(50.0, (self.height as f64) * 0.5);
        cairo_ctx.set_font_size(18.0);
        cairo_ctx.show_text("The only curse they could afford to put on a tomb these days was 'Bugger Off'. --PTerry");
        cairo_ctx.restore();
    }

    fn on_size_allocate(&mut self, rect: &RectangleInt) {
        self.width = rect.width as i32;
        self.height = rect.height as i32;
    }
}

fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to initialize GTK."));
    println!("Major: {}, Minor: {}", gtk::get_major_version(), gtk::get_minor_version());

    let window = RenderingAPITestWindow::new(800, 500);
    window.exit_on_close();
    gtk::main();
}
```

I arrived at this through a few observations:

- The instance is being shared across multiple closures for an undetermined amount of time. `Rc` is the *right* answer to that scenario because it provides shared ownership. `Rc` is very ergonomic to use; it works like any other pointer type.
- The only part of `instance` that is actually mutated is your state. Since your instance is being shared, it cannot be borrowed mutably using the standard `&mut` pointer. Therefore, you must use interior mutability. This is what `RefCell` provides. Note though, that you only need to use `RefCell` on the state you're mutating. So this still separates out the state into a separate struct, but it works nicely IMO.
- A possible modification to this code is to add `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` to the definition of the `RenderingState` struct. Since it can be `Copy` (because all of its component types are `Copy`), you can use [`Cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) instead of `RefCell`.

Comment: Thanks! That improves matters significantly! :)

Comment: @GeoffFrench It looks like you're new to StackOverflow, but if you think I've adequately answered your question then you should mark it as accepted. :-) Thanks!