# How to use gtk::DrawingArea?

Tags: rust, gtk

I am trying to build a GUI in Rust using GTK, Cairo and Glade. I want to draw a playing field using `gtk::DrawingArea` but I do not know how to use it. I have this:

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate gtk;

use gtk::*;

fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap(); //init gtk before using it

    let glade_src = include_str!("Glade_gui.glade"); //build the glade gui
    let builder = gtk::Builder::new_from_string(glade_src);

    //get widgets from the gui
    let draw_area: gtk::DrawingArea = builder.get_object("zeichenbrett").unwrap();
    let window: gtk::Window = builder.get_object("fenster").unwrap();

    let size = (600, 600); //define the size for the image

    let style_context: gtk::StyleContext = draw_area.get_style_context().unwrap(); //get the style context from the drawing area
    let surface: cairo::ImageSurface =
        cairo::ImageSurface::create(cairo::Format::ARgb32, size.0, size.1).unwrap(); //build a new ImageSurface to draw on
    let context: cairo::Context = cairo::Context::new(&surface); //build a new cairo context from that ImageSurface to draw on

    //just a blue area
    context.set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    context.paint();
    context.stroke();

    gtk::functions::render_background(
        &style_context,
        &context,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        size.0 as f64,
        size.1 as f64,
    ); //here I thought that I drew the context                        cairo::Context to the drawingArea but it seems to do nothing.

    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

It compiles and runs, but no playing field is shown on the window.

I think I am not using the `render_background` function correctly, but I do not know how to do it right.

Here is the [Glade_gui.glade](https://pastebin.com/yuAGxFfb) file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="fenster">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Reise nach Jerusalem</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="spacing">5</property>
            <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="links">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Left</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="rechts">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Right</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="quit">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Quit</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="zeichenbrett">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: You need to do the drawing in the `draw` signal for your `DrawingArea`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31967816/5397009) should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, I have no experience in Rust, so I'll use mainly C examples.

You are attempting to render your GUI before starting `gtk::main`. The proper way to implement a GTK+ GUI is to add your widgets, connect their `draw` signal (and any other necessary signals) to your own draw callback function, then run `gtk::main`.

As an example, take the documentation's simple GtkDrawingArea example found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html#GtkDrawingArea.description). In this example, `g_signal_connect` is used to connect the `draw` signal to the `draw_callback` callback function. This way, when the widget is actually created by `gtk::main`, it will draw your desired image on it.

Your `draw_callback` function will get a Cairo context as a parameter. You will do all your drawing on that context, so there is no need to create your own. This is also demonstrated in the docs by the use of the pointer `cr` in the parameters of `draw_callback`.

All your drawing needs to be done in the `draw` callback function. It will get called anytime an update is necessary (including creation of the GtkDrawingArea widget), or you can force an update by emitting the `queue_draw` signal.

The [C docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) can be a great help even when using a different language, especially if your chosen language doesn't have comprehensive documentation.

Also, the recommended modern way to create a GTK+ application is to use [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html). You may want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to spend several hours to find a solution with gtk-rs and GTK4 as there are very few examples. In GTK4, instead of connecting a draw signal, the draw functions must be registered with `gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func`. With the Rust bindings, we need to use `DrawingAreaExtManual::set_draw_func` to set the draw function. In my case, I was subclassing DrawingArea, which gave something like this:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::f64::consts::PI;

use glib::Object;
use gtk::gdk::RGBA;
use gtk::glib;
use gtk::glib::{clone, ParamSpec, Properties, Value};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::subclass::prelude::*;

mod imp {
    use super::*;

    // Object holding the state
    #[derive(Properties)]
    #[properties(wrapper_type = super::CustomDrawingArea)]
    pub struct CustomDrawingArea {
        #[property(name = "color", get, set)]
        pub(super) color: Cell<RGBA>,
    }

    impl Default for CustomDrawingArea {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self {
                color: Cell::new(RGBA::BLACK),
            }
        }
    }

    // The central trait for subclassing a GObject
    #[glib::object_subclass]
    impl ObjectSubclass for CustomDrawingArea {
        const NAME: &'static str = "CustomDrawingArea";
        type Type = super::CustomDrawingArea;
        type ParentType = gtk::DrawingArea;
    }

    impl ObjectImpl for CustomDrawingArea {
        fn constructed(&self) {
            self.parent_constructed();

            // Set the drawing function. This draws a circle filled with the color and a black outline.
            DrawingAreaExtManual::set_draw_func(self.obj().as_ref(), clone!(@weak self as widget => move |_, cr, w, h| {
                let r = w as f64 / 2.0 - 1.0;

                cr.arc(w as f64 / 2.0, h as f64 / 2.0, r, 0.0, 2.0 * PI);
                GdkCairoContextExt::set_source_rgba(cr, &widget.color.get());
                cr.fill().unwrap();

                cr.set_line_width(1.0);
                cr.arc(w as f64 / 2.0, h as f64 / 2.0, r, 0.0, 2.0 * PI);
                GdkCairoContextExt::set_source_rgba(cr, &RGBA::BLACK);
                cr.stroke().unwrap();
            }));

            // Make sure to redraw when the property is updated. 
            self.obj().connect_color_notify(|widget| widget.queue_draw());
        }

        // This is needed for the #[property] macro.
        fn properties() -> &'static [ParamSpec] {
            Self::derived_properties()
        }

        fn set_property(&self, id: usize, value: &Value, pspec: &ParamSpec) {
            self.derived_set_property(id, value, pspec)
        }

        fn property(&self, id: usize, pspec: &ParamSpec) -> Value {
            self.derived_property(id, pspec)
        }
    }

    impl WidgetImpl for CustomDrawingArea {}
    impl DrawingAreaImpl for CustomDrawingArea {}
}

glib::wrapper! {
    pub struct CustomDrawingArea(ObjectSubclass<imp::CustomDrawingArea>)
        @extends gtk::DrawingArea, gtk::Widget,
        @implements gtk::Accessible, gtk::Actionable, gtk::Buildable, gtk::ConstraintTarget;
}

impl CustomDrawingArea {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Object::builder().build()
    }
}
```